# Angular signals binding do not update properly

Tags: angular, signals

I am using signals to update a directive attributes binding my directive attributes to signals

```js
@Directive({
  host: {
    '[attr.verticalUsed]': 'scrollbarService.verticalUsed()',
    '[attr.horizontalUsed]': 'scrollbarService.horizontalUsed()',
    '[attr.isVerticallyScrollable]': 'scrollbarService.isVerticallyScrollable()',
    '[attr.isHorizontallyScrollable]': 'scrollbarService.isHorizontallyScrollable()'
  }
})
```

I realized that the attributes are not updating instantly, sometimes only updates after a change detection is triggered like clicking on a button in the app.

[image: Recording 2024-01-06 042453]

As seen in the gif above, when the horizontal scrollbar disappears, the vertical scrollbar should go full height, but it does not until I click somewhere.

When  commented out the attributes bindings and updated the DOM attribute directly inside the computed signal, the attributes were updated instantly as expected.

```js
horizontalUsed: Signal<boolean> = computed(() => {
  this.viewport.nativeElement.setAttribute('horizontalUsed', `${this.state().horizontalUsed}`)
  return this.state().horizontalUsed
});
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this? knowing that my signals get updated via the `ResizeObserver` and within Angular zone.

Comment: please share a stackblitz also